# NodeJS - how to return arrays from a module

Tags: arrays, node.js, module, export, return

I've got a module called 'userinfo.js' retrieving info about users from DB. Here's the code:

```
exports.getUserInfo = function(id){
db.collection("users", function (err, collection) {
    var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(String(id));
    collection.findOne({ _id: obj_id }, function (err, doc) {
        if (doc) {
            var profile = new Array();
            profile['username']=doc.username;
            return profile;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
}
```

From index.js (controller for index page, from which I'm trying to access userinfo) in a such way:

```
var userinfo = require('../userinfo.js');

var profile = userinfo.getUserInfo(req.currentUser._id);
console.log(profile['username']);
```

Node returns me such an error:

```
console.log(profile['username']);   -->     TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're returning `profile['username']` not the `profile` array itself.

Also you could return `false`, so you should check `profile` before accessing it.

EDIT. Looking over it again, your return statement is inside a callback closure. So your function is returning undefined. One possible solution, (keeping with node's async nature):

```
exports.getUserInfo = function(id,cb){
db.collection("users", function (err, collection) {
    var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(String(id));
    collection.findOne({ _id: obj_id }, function (err, doc) {
        if (doc) {
            var profile = new Array();
            profile['username']=doc.username;
            cb(err,profile);
        } else {
            cb(err,null);
        }
    });
```

});
}

```
    var userinfo = require('../userinfo.js');

    userinfo.getUserInfo(req.currentUser._id, function(err,profile){

      if(profile){
       console.log(profile['username']);
      }else{
       console.log(err);
      }
});
```

Comment: oh sorry, it's my mistake of testing. I've corrected to return profile; and still doesn't work.

Comment: an error is the same: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: your return statement is inside a callback closure. So your function is returning undefined- I have updated my answer.

Comment: it worked, thank you very much. However, according to this sample I'm forced to use async coding-style with callbacks, it would be nice to get smth like var profile = userinfo.getUserInfo(req.currentUser._id);   in the main module... Are there any variants without callbacks?

Comment: You should always use async (as your DB api does) in node to keep the main loop "free" to handle other requests. If you don't mind blocking (say on app startup) you could search for a sync DB api. Otherwise when wrapping async libraries it is far easier (and better!) to use callbacks.

Comment: thnx spacious it worked for me, is ther any other method to get this

Comment: @spacious The problem is that the output is logged, hence you cannot actually use its value. Is there a way so that you can store that value in a variable: `var x = userinfo.getUserInfo(...);`??